# Embed Jira Issue Details in Connfluence page

Tags: jira, confluence

I am currently looking for a way to integrate detail views of selected Jira Issues into a Conflluennce page. It seems it is not a problem at all to embed a list of Issues into confluence, but I am looking for a way to integrate the detail-view of a single Jira Issue into a Conflluence page.

The reason I need this, is that I am currently defining a workflow for formmally planning a Project. Currently I export the Issues of a Project version to Word and then update the resulting document to become a formal specification document. I would now like to do this in Confuence.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved my problem by creating my own confluence macro that accesses Jira using the REST interface. Works like a charm. If I find the time, I'll try to make it generally available (currently It's extremely tied to our configuration (hard-coded urls and credentials) Will be looking forward to utilizing the trusted communication features in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is available in the latest Confluence version, 3.5.  [Here's the documentation.](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Inserting+JIRA+Issues)

Comment: Ok ... I seem to have missed that icon ;-) ... but unfortunately this is still not what I am looking for.

Even if this allows me to insert individual Issues, this only inserts some very rudimentary information. I would like to insert the full Issue with all of it's fields. 

The reason is that I want to use Confluence for creating my Project Contracts. I want to create a document and include the full Issues where I reference them. When exporting this document I would like to have my project contract ready to be signed.

Comment: Oh, I see - the only way I could find to do that is to use the html-include macro to include the URL of the JIRA issue, but that only works if your JIRA allows anonymous browsing.  I'll keep looking around - I'd also recommend asking Atlassian support if you have it.